# merging a large list of xts objects

Tags: r, list, merge, xts, zoo

I have a list of `xts` objects that are mutually exclusive days. I would like to `merge` the list into one large `xts` object.  My attempt at doing this was to"

```
merged_reg_1_min_prices <- do.call(cbind, reg_1_min_prices)
```

However this seems to run out of memory.  `reg_1_min_prices` is 6,000 days of 1 minute returns  on mutually exclusive days so it's not very large.  Does anyone know how to get around this?

To be clear: `reg_1_min_prices` contains mutually exclusive days with 1 minute prices on each day and each entry in the list is an `xts` object.

Comment: Is `reg_1_min_prices` a list of 6,000 xts objects, where each list element is 1-minute data for a single day?

Comment: yes. apologies, let me add that to the question

Comment: Are you sure your want `cbind` instead of `rbind`? If you want to `rbind` the data, [this function](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/qmao/R/do.call.rbind.R?view=markup&root=twsinstrument) may help

Comment: i tried `merge`, `rbind` and `cbind`. all of them fail unfortunately and run up the memory usage from aourn 4 gigs to about 60 gigs.

Comment: The function I referenced above is used in `FinancialInstrument:::getSymbols.FI` which works well to load and merge lots of days of high frequency data.

Comment: interesting: i did the same thing just in a `for` loop because i thought it would use less memory but it still increased rapidly. i'll give your function a shot. this might be a more systemic problem though since my data is pretty small?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use the strategy provided by [Dominik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038464/dominik) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8071176/967840) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224938/can-i-rbind-be-parallelized-in-r)

I have turned it into a [function](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/qmao/R/do.call.rbind.R?view=markup&root=twsinstrument) in my [qmao](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1113) package.  This code is also at the core of [getSymbols.FI](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/FinancialInstrument/R/load.instruments.R?view=markup&root=blotter) in the [FinancialInstrument package](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=316).

```
do.call.rbind <- function(lst) {
  while(length(lst) > 1) {
    idxlst <- seq(from=1, to=length(lst), by=2)
    lst <- lapply(idxlst, function(i) {
      if(i==length(lst)) { return(lst[[i]]) }
      return(rbind(lst[[i]], lst[[i+1]]))
    })
  }
  lst[[1]]
}
```

If you want to `rbind` `data.frames`, [@JoshuaUlrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271616/joshua-ulrich) has provided an elegant solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9730292/967840)

---

As far as I can tell (without looking very closely) memory is not an issue with any of the three solutions offered ([@JoshuaUlrich's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12029663/967840), [@Alex's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12029010/967840), and qmao::do.call.rbind).  So, it comes down to speed...

```
library(xts)
l <- lapply(Sys.Date()-6000:1, function(x) {
    N=60*8;xts(rnorm(N),as.POSIXct(x)-seq(N*60,1,-60))})
GS <- do.call.rbind
JU <- function(x) Reduce(rbind, x)
Alex <- function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(x, as.data.frame)) #returns data.frame, not xts

identical(GS(l), JU(l)) #TRUE

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(GS(l), JU(l), Alex(l), replications=1)
     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
3 Alex(l)            1  89.575 109.9080    56.584   33.044          0         0
1   GS(l)            1   0.815   1.0000     0.599    0.216          0         0
2   JU(l)            1 209.783 257.4025   143.353   66.555          0         0
```

`do.call.rbind` clearly wins on speed.

Answer (score 10):

You don't want to use `merge` because that would return a 6000-column object with a row for each row in each list element (2,880,000 in my example).  And most of the values will be `NA`.  `cbind.xts` simply calls `merge.xts` with a few default argument values, so you don't want to use that either.

We're aware of the memory problem caused by calling `rbind.xts` via `do.call`.  Jeff does have more efficient code, but it's a prototype that is not public.

An alternative to [@GSee's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12029366/271616) is to use `Reduce`.  This takes awhile to run on my laptop, but memory is not an issue even with only 4GB.

```
library(xts)
l <- lapply(Sys.Date()-6000:1, function(x) {
  N=60*8;xts(rnorm(N),as.POSIXct(x)-seq(N*60,1,-60))})
x <- Reduce(rbind, l)
```

Comment: great! what is Reduce? i can't seem to find an R ref to it

Comment: @Alex: it's a function in the base package.  See `?Reduce`.

Comment: +1 for explaining why `cbind` wasn't what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do this efficiently: convert each `xts` object to a `data.frame` and simply `rbind` them.  This does not raise the memory usage almost at all.  If necessary then simply create a new `xts` object from the `data.frame`

Comment: I don't think `do.call.rbind` uses much memory either, and it's magnitudes faster for the data I've tested (not even including the time to convert back to `xts`).

Comment: ok cool, let me give it a shot. do you happen to know what it is about the normal rbind that screws it all up?

Comment: No, but I bet @JoshuaUlrich does.  If I recall correctly, Jeff has some uncommitted code to do this much more efficiently.