# Is there a work around for slow performance of do.call(cbind.xts,...) in R 2.15.2?

Tags: r, xts

I would expect `cbind.xts` and `do.call(cbind.xts)` to perform with similar elapsed time.
That was true for R2.11, R2.14.

For R2.15.2 and **xts** 0.8-8, the `do.call(cbind.xts,...)` variant performs **drastically slower**, which effectively breaks my previous codes.

As Josh Ulrich notes in a comment below, the **xts** package maintainers are aware of this problem. In the meantime, is there a convenient work around?

Reproducible example:

```
library(xts)

secs <- function (rows, from = as.character(Sys.time()), cols = 1, by = 1) 
{
    deltas <- seq(from = 0, by = by, length.out = rows)
    nacol <- matrix(data = NA, ncol = cols, nrow = rows)
    xts(x = nacol, order.by = strptime(from, format = "%Y-%m-%d %X") + 
        deltas)
}

n <- 20
d1 <- secs(rows=n*100,cols=n)
d2 <- secs(rows=n*100,cols=n)

system.time(cbind.xts(d1,d2))
```

versus

```
system.time(do.call(cbind.xts, list(d1,d2)))
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the place to confirm behavior. You could edit your question to ask for a work-around. That said, we're aware of this and it has to do with `do.call` (and perhaps the unusual method dispatch of `cbind` and `rbind`); it is not specific to xts.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Well, who is aware of it? R-core team? Or xts team? What is the details of the problem? Please provide better information.

Comment: @PetrMatousu: Maybe you should learn who your package maintainers are.

Comment: Here's a work around to make `do.call(rbind.xts, ...)` faster.  Maybe it'd help with `do.call(cbind.xts, ...)`, I dunno. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12029366/967840

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I removed his timong code in my edit, thinking it wasn't necessary. Feel free to roll back.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One work-around is to set `quote=TRUE` in `do.call`.

```
R> system.time(cb <- cbind.xts(d1,d2))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.004   0.000   0.004 
R> system.time(dc <- do.call(cbind.xts, list(d1,d2), quote=TRUE))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   0.004   0.004 
R> identical(cb,dc)
[1] TRUE
```

The slowness is caused by `do.call` evaluating the arguments before evaluating the function call by default, which causes the call to be much larger. For example, compare these two calls:

```
call("cbind", d1, d2)                # huge
call("cbind", quote(d1), quote(d2))  # dainty
```