# Alternative to do.call for large datasets

Tags: r, do.call

I love `do.call`.  I love being able to store function arguments in a list and then splatting them to a given function.

For example, I often find myself using this pattern to fit a list of different predictive models, with some shared and some unique parameters for each model:

```
library(caret)
global_args <- list(
  x=iris[,1:3],
  y=iris[,4],
  trControl=trainControl(
    method='cv',
    number=2,
    returnResamp='final',
    )
  )
global_args$trControl$index <- createFolds(
  global_args$y,
  global_args$trControl$number
  )
model_specific_args <- list(
  'lm' = list(method='lm', tuneLength=1),
  'nn' = list(method='nnet', tuneLength=3, trace=FALSE),
  'gbm' = list(
    method='gbm',
    verbose=FALSE,
    tuneGrid=expand.grid(
      n.trees=1:100,
      interaction.depth=c(2, 3),
      shrinkage=c(.1, .01)
    )
  )
)
list_of_models <- lapply(model_specific_args, function(args){
  return(do.call(train, c(global_args, args), quote=TRUE))
})
resamps <- resamples(list_of_models)
dotplot(resamps, metric='RMSE')
```

`global_args` contains arguments that are the same for all of the models, and `model_specific_args` contains lists of model-specific arguments. I loop over `model_specific_args`, concatenate each element with `global_args`, and then use `do.call` to pass the final argument list to the model fitting function.

While this code is visually elegant, its performance is terrible: `do.call` literally serializes the entire x dataset as text and then passes it to the model fitting function.  If x is a few GB of data this uses an insane amount of RAM and usually fails.

```
print(list_of_models[[1]]$call)
```

Is there anyone way to pass a list of arguments to a function in R, without using `do.call` or `call`?

Comment: Have you tried rbind.fill from the plyr package. I haven't read the code to know if the end product is a data frame, but if so, then rbind.fill is substantially faster than the equivalent do.call(rbind, ...). In other cases, I've also had success using Reduce(.)

Comment: @jimmyb I don't think `rbind.fill` or `Reduce` are appropriate here.  I'm not trying to combine `data.frames`, I'm trying to pass lists of arguments to a function.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923301/is-there-a-work-around-for-slow-performance-of-do-callcbind-xts-in-r-2-15) help?

Comment: @r2evans adding `quote=TRUE` helps a little, but `do.call` is still serializing the entire data set before passing it to `train`.

Answer (score 1):

[`rlang::invoke`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/invoke.html) worked for me.

It is soft-deprecated in favour of `exec`, but still does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [fastDoCall](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Gmisc/versions/1.8.1/topics/fastDoCall) from [Gmisc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Gmisc/versions/1.8.1) package.

```r
library("ranger")
iris2 <- iris[c(1:10, 51:60, 101:110), ]

args <- list(dependent.variable.name = "Species"
             , data = iris2
             )

args2 <- list(dependent.variable.name = "Species"
             , data = as.name("iris2")
             )
# do.call with args2 (call prints the function but not data)
do.call(ranger, args2)
#> Ranger result
#> 
#> Call:
#>  (function (formula = NULL, data = NULL, num.trees = 500, mtry = NULL,      importance = "none", write.forest = TRUE, probability = FALSE,      min.node.size = NULL, max.depth = NULL, replace = TRUE, sample.fraction = ifelse(replace,          1, 0.632), case.weights = NULL, class.weights = NULL,      splitrule = NULL, num.random.splits = 1, alpha = 0.5, minprop = 0.1,      split.select.weights = NULL, always.split.variables = NULL,      respect.unordered.factors = NULL, scale.permutation.importance = FALSE,      keep.inbag = FALSE, inbag = NULL, holdout = FALSE, quantreg = FALSE,      oob.error = TRUE, num.threads = NULL, save.memory = FALSE,      verbose = TRUE, seed = NULL, dependent.variable.name = NULL,      status.variable.name = NULL, classification = NULL)  {     if ("gwaa.data" %in% class(data)) {         snp.names <- data@gtdata@snpnames         snp.data <- data@gtdata@gtps@.Data         data <- data@phdata         if ("id" %in% names(data)) {             data$id <- NULL         }         gwa.mode <- TRUE         save.memory <- FALSE     }     else {         snp.data <- as.matrix(0)         gwa.mode <- FALSE     }     if (inherits(data, "Matrix")) {         if (!("dgCMatrix" %in% class(data))) {             stop("Error: Currently only sparse data of class 'dgCMatrix' supported.")         }         if (!is.null(formula)) {             stop("Error: Sparse matrices only supported with alternative interface. Use dependent.variable.name instead of formula.")         }     }     if (is.null(formula)) {         if (is.null(dependent.variable.name)) {             stop("Error: Please give formula or dependent variable name.")         }         if (is.null(status.variable.name)) {             status.variable.name <- ""             response <- data[, dependent.variable.name, drop = TRUE]         }         else {             response <- survival::Surv(data[, dependent.variable.name],                  data[, status.variable.name])         }         data.selected <- data     }     else {         formula <- formula(formula)         if (class(formula) != "formula") {             stop("Error: Invalid formula.")         }         data.selected <- parse.formula(formula, data, env = parent.frame())         response <- data.selected[, 1]     }     if (any(is.na(data.selected))) {         offending_columns <- colnames(data.selected)[colSums(is.na(data.selected)) >              0]         stop("Missing data in columns: ", paste0(offending_columns,              collapse = ", "), ".", call. = FALSE)     }     if (is.factor(response)) {         if (nlevels(response) != nlevels(droplevels(response))) {             dropped_levels <- setdiff(levels(response), levels(droplevels(response)))             warning("Dropped unused factor level(s) in dependent variable: ",                  paste0(dropped_levels, collapse = ", "), ".",                  call. = FALSE)         }     }     if (is.factor(response)) {         if (probability) {             treetype <- 9         }         else {             treetype <- 1         }     }     else if (is.numeric(response) && (is.null(ncol(response)) ||          ncol(response) == 1)) {         if (!is.null(classification) && classification && !probability) {             treetype <- 1         }         else if (probability) {             treetype <- 9         }         else {             treetype <- 3         }     }     else if (class(response) == "Surv" || is.data.frame(response) ||          is.matrix(response)) {         treetype <- 5     }     else {         stop("Error: Unsupported type of dependent variable.")     }     if (quantreg && treetype != 3) {         stop("Error: Quantile prediction implemented only for regression outcomes.")     }     if (!is.null(formula)) {         if (treetype == 5) {             dependent.variable.name <- dimnames(response)[[2]][1]             status.variable.name <- dimnames(response)[[2]][2]         }         else {             dependent.variable.name <- names(data.selected)[1]             status.variable.name <- ""         }         independent.variable.names <- names(data.selected)[-1]     }     else {         independent.variable.names <- colnames(data.selected)[colnames(data.selected) !=              dependent.variable.name & colnames(data.selected) !=              status.variable.name]     }     if (is.null(respect.unordered.factors)) {         if (!is.null(splitrule) && splitrule == "extratrees") {             respect.unordered.factors <- "partition"         }         else {             respect.unordered.factors <- "ignore"         }     }     if (respect.unordered.factors == TRUE) {         respect.unordered.factors <- "order"     }     else if (respect.unordered.factors == FALSE) {         respect.unordered.factors <- "ignore"     }     if (!is.matrix(data.selected) && !inherits(data.selected,          "Matrix")) {         character.idx <- sapply(data.selected, is.character)         if (respect.unordered.factors == "order") {             names.selected <- names(data.selected)             ordered.idx <- sapply(data.selected, is.ordered)             factor.idx <- sapply(data.selected, is.factor)             independent.idx <- names.selected != dependent.variable.name &                  names.selected != status.variable.name & names.selected !=                  paste0("Surv(", dependent.variable.name, ", ",                    status.variable.name, ")")             recode.idx <- independent.idx & (character.idx |                  (factor.idx & !ordered.idx))             if (any(recode.idx) & (importance == "impurity_corrected" ||                  importance == "impurity_unbiased")) {                 warning("Corrected impurity importance may not be unbiased for re-ordered factor levels. Consider setting respect.unordered.factors to 'ignore' or 'partition' or manually compute corrected importance.")             }             if (is.factor(response)) {                 num.response <- as.numeric(response)             }             else {                 num.response <- response             }             data.selected[recode.idx] <- lapply(data.selected[recode.idx],                  function(x) {                   if (!is.factor(x)) {                     x <- as.factor(x)                   }                   if ("Surv" %in% class(response)) {                     levels.ordered <- largest.quantile(response ~                        x)                     levels.missing <- setdiff(levels(x), levels.ordered)                     levels.ordered <- c(levels.missing, levels.ordered)                   }                   else if (is.factor(response) & nlevels(response) >                      2) {                     levels.ordered <- pca.order(y = response,                        x = x)                   }                   else {                     means <- sapply(levels(x), function(y) {                       mean(num.response[x == y])                     })                     levels.ordered <- as.character(levels(x)[order(means)])                   }                   factor(x, levels = levels.ordered, ordered = TRUE,                      exclude = NULL)                 })             covariate.levels <- lapply(data.selected[independent.idx],                  levels)         }         else {             data.selected[character.idx] <- lapply(data.selected[character.idx],                  factor)         }     }     if (!is.null(formula) && treetype == 5) {         data.final <- data.matrix(cbind(response[, 1], response[,              2], data.selected[-1]))         colnames(data.final) <- c(dependent.variable.name, status.variable.name,              independent.variable.names)     }     else if (is.matrix(data.selected) || inherits(data.selected,          "Matrix")) {         data.final <- data.selected     }     else {         data.final <- data.matrix(data.selected)     }     variable.names <- colnames(data.final)     if (gwa.mode) {         variable.names <- c(variable.names, snp.names)         all.independent.variable.names <- c(independent.variable.names,              snp.names)     }     else {         all.independent.variable.names <- independent.variable.names     }     if (length(all.independent.variable.names) < 1) {         stop("Error: No covariates found.")     }     if (!is.numeric(num.trees) || num.trees < 1) {         stop("Error: Invalid value for num.trees.")     }     if (is.null(mtry)) {         mtry <- 0     }     else if (!is.numeric(mtry) || mtry < 0) {         stop("Error: Invalid value for mtry")     }     if (is.null(seed)) {         seed <- runif(1, 0, .Machine$integer.max)     }     if (!is.logical(keep.inbag)) {         stop("Error: Invalid value for keep.inbag")     }     if (is.null(num.threads)) {         num.threads = 0     }     else if (!is.numeric(num.threads) || num.threads < 0) {         stop("Error: Invalid value for num.threads")     }     if (is.null(min.node.size)) {         min.node.size <- 0     }     else if (!is.numeric(min.node.size) || min.node.size < 0) {         stop("Error: Invalid value for min.node.size")     }     if (is.null(max.depth)) {         max.depth <- 0     }     else if (!is.numeric(max.depth) || max.depth < 0) {         stop("Error: Invalid value for max.depth. Please give a positive integer.")     }     if (!is.numeric(sample.fraction)) {         stop("Error: Invalid value for sample.fraction. Please give a value in (0,1] or a vector of values in [0,1].")     }     if (length(sample.fraction) > 1) {         if (!(treetype %in% c(1, 9))) {             stop("Error: Invalid value for sample.fraction. Vector values only valid for classification forests.")         }         if (any(sample.fraction < 0) || any(sample.fraction >              1)) {             stop("Error: Invalid value for sample.fraction. Please give a value in (0,1] or a vector of values in [0,1].")         }         if (sum(sample.fraction) <= 0) {             stop("Error: Invalid value for sample.fraction. Sum of values must be >0.")         }         if (length(sample.fraction) != nlevels(response)) {             stop("Error: Invalid value for sample.fraction. Expecting ",                  nlevels(response), " values, provided ", length(sample.fraction),                  ".")         }         if (!replace & any(sample.fraction * length(response) >              table(response))) {             idx <- which(sample.fraction * length(response) >                  table(response))[1]             stop("Error: Not enough samples in class ", names(idx),                  "; available: ", table(response)[idx], ", requested: ",                  (sample.fraction * length(response))[idx], ".")         }         if (!is.null(case.weights)) {             stop("Error: Combination of case.weights and class-wise sampling not supported.")         }     }     else {         if (sample.fraction <= 0 || sample.fraction > 1) {             stop("Error: Invalid value for sample.fraction. Please give a value in (0,1] or a vector of values in [0,1].")         }     }     if (is.null(importance) || importance == "none") {         importance.mode <- 0     }     else if (importance == "impurity") {         importance.mode <- 1     }     else if (importance == "impurity_corrected" || importance ==          "impurity_unbiased") {         importance.mode <- 5     }     else if (importance == "permutation") {         if (scale.permutation.importance) {             importance.mode <- 2         }         else {             importance.mode <- 3         }     }     else {         stop("Error: Unknown importance mode.")     }     if (is.null(case.weights)) {         case.weights <- c(0, 0)         use.case.weights <- FALSE         if (holdout) {             stop("Error: Case weights required to use holdout mode.")         }     }     else {         use.case.weights <- TRUE         if (holdout) {             sample.fraction <- sample.fraction * mean(case.weights >                  0)         }         if (!replace && sum(case.weights > 0) < sample.fraction *              nrow(data.final)) {             stop("Error: Fewer non-zero case weights than observations to sample.")         }     }     if (is.null(inbag)) {         inbag <- list(c(0, 0))         use.inbag <- FALSE     }     else if (is.list(inbag)) {         use.inbag <- TRUE         if (use.case.weights) {             stop("Error: Combination of case.weights and inbag not supported.")         }         if (length(sample.fraction) > 1) {             stop("Error: Combination of class-wise sampling and inbag not supported.")         }         if (length(inbag) != num.trees) {             stop("Error: Size of inbag list not equal to number of trees.")         }     }     else {         stop("Error: Invalid inbag, expects list of vectors of size num.trees.")     }     if (is.null(class.weights)) {         class.weights <- rep(1, nlevels(response))     }     else {         if (!(treetype %in% c(1, 9))) {             stop("Error: Argument class.weights only valid for classification forests.")         }         if (!is.numeric(class.weights) || any(class.weights <              0)) {             stop("Error: Invalid value for class.weights. Please give a vector of non-negative values.")         }         if (length(class.weights) != nlevels(response)) {             stop("Error: Number of class weights not equal to number of classes.")         }         class.weights <- class.weights[unique(as.numeric(response))]     }     if (is.null(split.select.weights)) {         split.select.weights <- list(c(0, 0))         use.split.select.weights <- FALSE     }     else if (is.numeric(split.select.weights)) {         if (length(split.select.weights) != length(all.independent.variable.names)) {             stop("Error: Number of split select weights not equal to number of independent variables.")         }         split.select.weights <- list(split.select.weights)         use.split.select.weights <- TRUE     }     else if (is.list(split.select.weights)) {         if (length(split.select.weights) != num.trees) {             stop("Error: Size of split select weights list not equal to number of trees.")         }         use.split.select.weights <- TRUE     }     else {         stop("Error: Invalid split select weights.")     }     if (is.null(always.split.variables)) {         always.split.variables <- c("0", "0")         use.always.split.variables <- FALSE     }     else {         use.always.split.variables <- TRUE     }     if (use.split.select.weights && use.always.split.variables) {         stop("Error: Please use only one option of split.select.weights and always.split.variables.")     }     if (is.null(splitrule)) {         if (treetype == 5) {             splitrule <- "logrank"         }         else if (treetype == 3) {             splitrule <- "variance"         }         else if (treetype %in% c(1, 9)) {             splitrule <- "gini"         }         splitrule.num <- 1     }     else if (splitrule == "logrank") {         if (treetype == 5) {             splitrule.num <- 1         }         else {             stop("Error: logrank splitrule applicable to survival data only.")         }     }     else if (splitrule == "gini") {         if (treetype %in% c(1, 9)) {             splitrule.num <- 1         }         else {             stop("Error: Gini splitrule applicable to classification data only.")         }     }     else if (splitrule == "variance") {         if (treetype == 3) {             splitrule.num <- 1         }         else {             stop("Error: variance splitrule applicable to regression data only.")         }     }     else if (splitrule == "auc" || splitrule == "C") {         if (treetype == 5) {             splitrule.num <- 2         }         else {             stop("Error: C index splitrule applicable to survival data only.")         }     }     else if (splitrule == "auc_ignore_ties" || splitrule == "C_ignore_ties") {         if (treetype == 5) {             splitrule.num <- 3         }         else {             stop("Error: C index splitrule applicable to survival data only.")         }     }     else if (splitrule == "maxstat") {         if (treetype == 5 || treetype == 3) {             splitrule.num <- 4         }         else {             stop("Error: maxstat splitrule applicable to regression or survival data only.")         }     }     else if (splitrule == "extratrees") {         splitrule.num <- 5     }     else {         stop("Error: Unknown splitrule.")     }     if (alpha < 0 || alpha > 1) {         stop("Error: Invalid value for alpha, please give a value between 0 and 1.")     }     if (minprop < 0 || minprop > 0.5) {         stop("Error: Invalid value for minprop, please give a value between 0 and 0.5.")     }     if (!is.numeric(num.random.splits) || num.random.splits <          1) {         stop("Error: Invalid value for num.random.splits, please give a positive integer.")     }     if (splitrule.num == 5 && save.memory && respect.unordered.factors ==          "partition") {         stop("Error: save.memory option not possible in extraTrees mode with unordered predictors.")     }     if (respect.unordered.factors == "partition") {         names.selected <- names(data.selected)         ordered.idx <- sapply(data.selected, is.ordered)         factor.idx <- sapply(data.selected, is.factor)         independent.idx <- names.selected != dependent.variable.name &              names.selected != status.variable.name         unordered.factor.variables <- names.selected[factor.idx &              !ordered.idx & independent.idx]         if (length(unordered.factor.variables) > 0) {             use.unordered.factor.variables <- TRUE             num.levels <- sapply(data.selected[, factor.idx &                  !ordered.idx & independent.idx, drop = FALSE],                  nlevels)             max.level.count <- .Machine$double.digits             if (max(num.levels) > max.level.count) {                 stop(paste("Too many levels in unordered categorical variable ",                    unordered.factor.variables[which.max(num.levels)],                    ". Only ", max.level.count, " levels allowed on this system. Consider using the 'order' option.",                    sep = ""))             }         }         else {             unordered.factor.variables <- c("0", "0")             use.unordered.factor.variables <- FALSE         }     }     else if (respect.unordered.factors == "ignore" || respect.unordered.factors ==          "order") {         unordered.factor.variables <- c("0", "0")         use.unordered.factor.variables <- FALSE     }     else {         stop("Error: Invalid value for respect.unordered.factors, please use 'order', 'partition' or 'ignore'.")     }     if (use.unordered.factor.variables && !is.null(splitrule)) {         if (splitrule == "maxstat") {             stop("Error: Unordered factor splitting not implemented for 'maxstat' splitting rule.")         }         else if (splitrule %in% c("C", "auc", "C_ignore_ties",              "auc_ignore_ties")) {             stop("Error: Unordered factor splitting not implemented for 'C' splitting rule.")         }     }     if (respect.unordered.factors == "order") {         if (treetype == 3 && splitrule == "maxstat") {             warning("Warning: The 'order' mode for unordered factor handling with the 'maxstat' splitrule is experimental.")         }         if (gwa.mode & ((treetype %in% c(1, 9) & nlevels(response) >              2) | treetype == 5)) {             stop("Error: Ordering of SNPs currently only implemented for regression and binary outcomes.")         }     }     prediction.mode <- FALSE     predict.all <- FALSE     prediction.type <- 1     loaded.forest <- list()     if ("dgCMatrix" %in% class(data.final)) {         sparse.data <- data.final         data.final <- matrix(c(0, 0))         use.sparse.data <- TRUE     }     else {         sparse.data <- Matrix(matrix(c(0, 0)))         use.sparse.data <- FALSE     }     if (respect.unordered.factors == "order") {         order.snps <- TRUE     }     else {         order.snps <- FALSE     }     rm("data.selected")     result <- rangerCpp(treetype, dependent.variable.name, data.final,          variable.names, mtry, num.trees, verbose, seed, num.threads,          write.forest, importance.mode, min.node.size, split.select.weights,          use.split.select.weights, always.split.variables, use.always.split.variables,          status.variable.name, prediction.mode, loaded.forest,          snp.data, replace, probability, unordered.factor.variables,          use.unordered.factor.variables, save.memory, splitrule.num,          case.weights, use.case.weights, class.weights, predict.all,          keep.inbag, sample.fraction, alpha, minprop, holdout,          prediction.type, num.random.splits, sparse.data, use.sparse.data,          order.snps, oob.error, max.depth, inbag, use.inbag)     if (length(result) == 0) {         stop("User interrupt or internal error.")     }     if (importance.mode != 0) {         names(result$variable.importance) <- all.independent.variable.names     }     if (treetype == 1 && is.factor(response) && oob.error) {         result$predictions <- integer.to.factor(result$predictions,              levels(response))         true.values <- integer.to.factor(unlist(data.final[,              dependent.variable.name]), levels(response))         result$confusion.matrix <- table(true.values, result$predictions,              dnn = c("true", "predicted"), useNA = "ifany")     }     else if (treetype == 5 && oob.error) {         if (is.list(result$predictions)) {             result$predictions <- do.call(rbind, result$predictions)         }         if (is.vector(result$predictions)) {             result$predictions <- matrix(result$predictions,                  nrow = 1)         }         result$chf <- result$predictions         result$predictions <- NULL         result$survival <- exp(-result$chf)     }     else if (treetype == 9 && !is.matrix(data) && oob.error) {         if (is.list(result$predictions)) {             result$predictions <- do.call(rbind, result$predictions)         }         if (is.vector(result$predictions)) {             result$predictions <- matrix(result$predictions,                  nrow = 1)         }         colnames(result$predictions) <- unique(response)         if (is.factor(response)) {             result$predictions <- result$predictions[, levels(droplevels(response)),                  drop = FALSE]         }     }     result$splitrule <- splitrule     if (treetype == 1) {         result$treetype <- "Classification"     }     else if (treetype == 3) {         result$treetype <- "Regression"     }     else if (treetype == 5) {         result$treetype <- "Survival"     }     else if (treetype == 9) {         result$treetype <- "Probability estimation"     }     if (treetype == 3) {         result$r.squared <- 1 - result$prediction.error/var(response)     }     result$call <- sys.call()     result$importance.mode <- importance     result$num.samples <- nrow(data.final)     result$replace <- replace     if (write.forest) {         if (is.factor(response)) {             result$forest$levels <- levels(response)         }         result$forest$independent.variable.names <- independent.variable.names         result$forest$treetype <- result$treetype         class(result$forest) <- "ranger.forest"         if (respect.unordered.factors == "order" && !is.matrix(data)) {             result$forest$covariate.levels <- covariate.levels         }     }     class(result) <- "ranger"     if (quantreg) {         terminal.nodes <- predict(result, data, type = "terminalNodes")$predictions +              1         n <- result$num.samples         result$random.node.values <- matrix(nrow = max(terminal.nodes),              ncol = num.trees)         for (tree in 1:num.trees) {             idx <- sample(1:n, n)             result$random.node.values[terminal.nodes[idx, tree],                  tree] <- response[idx]         }         if (!is.null(result$inbag.counts)) {             inbag.counts <- simplify2array(result$inbag.counts)             random.node.values.oob <- 0 * terminal.nodes             random.node.values.oob[inbag.counts > 0] <- NA             for (tree in 1:num.trees) {                 is.oob <- inbag.counts[, tree] == 0                 num.oob <- sum(is.oob)                 if (num.oob != 0) {                   oob.obs <- which(is.oob)                   oob.nodes <- terminal.nodes[oob.obs, tree]                   for (j in 1:num.oob) {                     idx <- terminal.nodes[, tree] == oob.nodes[j]                     idx[oob.obs[j]] <- FALSE                     random.node.values.oob[oob.obs[j], tree] <- save.sample(response[idx],                        size = 1)                   }                 }             }             minoob <- min(rowSums(inbag.counts == 0))             if (minoob < 10) {                 stop("Error: Too few trees for out-of-bag quantile regression.")             }             result$random.node.values.oob <- t(apply(random.node.values.oob,                  1, function(x) {                   sample(x[!is.na(x)], minoob)                 }))         }     }     return(result) })(dependent.variable.name = "Species", data = iris2) 
#> 
#> Type:                             Classification 
#> Number of trees:                  500 
#> Sample size:                      30 
#> Number of independent variables:  4 
#> Mtry:                             2 
#> Target node size:                 1 
#> Variable importance mode:         none 
#> Splitrule:                        gini 
#> OOB prediction error:             3.33 %

# Gmisc fastDoCall (cleaner and faster)
Gmisc::fastDoCall(ranger, args)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
#>   method         from 
#>   [.quosures     rlang
#>   c.quosures     rlang
#>   print.quosures rlang
#> Ranger result
#> 
#> Call:
#>  ranger(dependent.variable.name = dependent.variable.name, data = data) 
#> 
#> Type:                             Classification 
#> Number of trees:                  500 
#> Sample size:                      30 
#> Number of independent variables:  4 
#> Mtry:                             2 
#> Target node size:                 1 
#> Variable importance mode:         none 
#> Splitrule:                        gini 
#> OOB prediction error:             3.33 %
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @r2evans comment, here is one possible solution: `quote()` the large objects in the list of arguments.  They will then be pulled from the global environment when `do.call` evaluates the function:

```
library(caret)
x <- iris[,1:3]
y <- iris[,4]
global_args <- list(
  x=quote(x),
  y=quote(y),
  trControl=trainControl(
    method='cv',
    number=2,
    returnResamp='final'
  )
)
global_args$trControl$index <- createFolds(
  y,
  global_args$trControl$number
)
model_specific_args <- list(
  'lm' = list(method='lm', tuneLength=1),
  'nn' = list(method='nnet', tuneLength=3, trace=FALSE),
  'gbm' = list(
    method='gbm',
    verbose=FALSE,
    tuneGrid=expand.grid(
      n.trees=1:100,
      interaction.depth=c(2, 3),
      shrinkage=c(.1, .01)
    )
  )
)
list_of_models <- lapply(model_specific_args, function(args){
  return(do.call(train, c(global_args, args), quote=FALSE))
})
print(list_of_models[[1]]$call)
```

The result is much smaller:

```
train.default(x = x, y = y, method = "lm", trControl = list(method = "cv", 
    number = 2, repeats = 1, p = 0.75, initialWindow = NULL, 
    horizon = 1, fixedWindow = TRUE, verboseIter = FALSE, returnData = TRUE, 
    returnResamp = "final", savePredictions = FALSE, classProbs = FALSE, 
    summaryFunction = function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) 
    {
        if (is.character(data$obs)) 
            data$obs <- factor(data$obs, levels = lev)
        postResample(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"])
    }, selectionFunction = "best", preProcOptions = list(thresh = 0.95, 
        ICAcomp = 3, k = 5), index = list(Fold1 = c(6L, 7L, 11L, 
    12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 21L, 22L, 25L, 26L, 29L, 32L, 34L, 
    35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 
    54L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 
    74L, 78L, 80L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 95L, 98L, 99L, 
    100L, 103L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 109L, 111L, 112L, 116L, 118L, 
    122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 128L, 130L, 132L, 133L, 135L, 138L, 
    141L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 148L), Fold2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 24L, 27L, 28L, 
    30L, 31L, 33L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 53L, 55L, 56L, 
    60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 68L, 73L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 79L, 81L, 82L, 
    86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 94L, 96L, 97L, 101L, 102L, 104L, 
    108L, 110L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 117L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 126L, 
    127L, 129L, 131L, 134L, 136L, 137L, 139L, 140L, 142L, 146L, 
    147L, 149L, 150L)), indexOut = NULL, timingSamps = 0, predictionBounds = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE), seeds = NA, adaptive = list(min = 5, alpha = 0.05, 
        method = "gls", complete = TRUE), allowParallel = TRUE), 
    tuneLength = 1)
```

It'd still be nice to not have to serialize all the other options though.  The third model's call in particular is still huge: `print(list_of_models[[3]]$call)`