# Merging multiple XTS objects by index

Tags: r, list, merge, xts

There are **multiple XTS objects**. Each one contains one column only (of prices).
The objects may be of different lengths. I want to **merge them by index**.
I can merge two XTS objects with `merge.xts`. But I want to merge multiple 
(with one function, without repeating merging process multiple times).

So I applied the approach recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028671/merging-a-large-list-of-xts-objects). It works. Just one issue: it merges all data into one column, rather than **placing each XTS object to be merged into its own column**. e.g. In the reproducible example, the desired end result is for XTSM to have 3 columns.

How can that be achieved? Thank you.

```
library('xts')

#Data
XTS1 <- structure(c(125.26, 125.14, 125.21, 125.26, 125.21, 125.26, 125.24, 125.22, 125.3, 125.32, 125.38, 125.38, 125.29, 125.26, 125.3, 125.25, 125.29, 125.37, 125.21, 125.3, 125.25, 125.24, 125.21, 125.24, 125.24, 125.26, 125.23, 125.23), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", .CLASS = "double", index = structure(c(1403537400, 1403538300, 1403539200, 1403540100, 1403541000, 1403541900, 1403542800, 1403543700, 1403544600, 1403545500, 1403546400, 1403547300, 1403548200, 1403549100, 1403550000, 1403550900, 1403551800, 1403552700, 1403553600, 1403554500, 1403555400, 1403556300, 1403557200, 1403560800, 1403561700, 1403562600, 1403563500, 1403564400), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(28L, 1L))
XTS2 <- structure(c(1867, 1867, 1868.5, 1868.75, 1868.75, 1868.75, 1868.25, 1867.25, 1867.5, 1867.75, 1868, 1868.25, 1868.25, 1868.75, 1868, 1868.5, 1869, 1869.75, 1868.75, 1868.5, 1868.25, 1867.5, 1867, 1866.75, 1866.75, 1867, 1867.5), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", .CLASS = "double", index = structure(c(1403537400, 1403538300, 1403539200, 1403540100, 1403541000, 1403541900, 1403542800, 1403543700, 1403544600, 1403545500, 1403546400, 1403547300, 1403548200, 1403549100, 1403550000, 1403550900, 1403551800, 1403552700, 1403553600, 1403555400, 1403556300, 1403557200, 1403560800, 1403561700, 1403562600, 1403563500, 1403564400), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(27L, 1L))
XTS3 <- structure(c(1867, 1867, 1868.5, 1868.75, 1868.75, 1868.75, 1868.25, 1867.25, 1867.5, 1867.75, 1868, 1868.25, 1868.25, 1868.75, 1868, 1868.5, 1869, 1869.75, 1868.75, 1868.5, 1868.25, 1867.5, 1867, 1866.75, 1866.75, 1867, 1867.5), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", .CLASS = "double", index = structure(c(1403537400, 1403538300, 1403539200, 1403540100, 1403541000, 1403541900, 1403542800, 1403543700, 1403544600, 1403545500, 1403546400, 1403547300, 1403548200, 1403549100, 1403550000, 1403550900, 1403551800, 1403552700, 1403553600, 1403555400, 1403556300, 1403557200, 1403560800, 1403561700, 1403562600, 1403563500, 1403564400), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(27L, 1L))

#Following code merges 2 xts objects into a 2 column xts
XTSM <- merge(XTS1,XTS2, all=TRUE)

#Following code merges multiple xts objects into a 1 column xts
XTSlist <- list(XTS1, XTS2, XTS3)

do.call.rbind <- function(lst) {
  while(length(lst) > 1) {
    idxlst <- seq(from=1, to=length(lst), by=2)
    lst <- lapply(idxlst, function(i) {
      if(i==length(lst)) { return(lst[[i]]) }
      return(rbind(lst[[i]], lst[[i+1]]))
    })
  }
  lst[[1]]
}

XTSM <- do.call.rbind (XTSlist)
```

Comment: `merge.xts` accepts more than 2 xts objects.  See `?merge.xts`

Comment: Indeed it does. That solved the issue. For some odd reason when I tried multiple objects with `merge.xts` before I was getting an error message. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `merge.xts` only accepts two arguments if `join` is not `"all"`.  Also note that you should just call `merge()`. It is not good practice to call methods directly.  There's nothing stopping you from calling, for example `merge.xts(data.frame(...))`, which could have unexpected results.

Comment: `mege.zoo` accepts multiple arguments in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joshua answer the question in the comments. Posting solution for the sake of having the Q answered. It is as simple as this:

```
XTSM.T <- merge(XTS1,XTS2,XTS3, all=TRUE)

or

XTSM.F <- merge(XTS1,XTS2,XTS3, all=FALSE)
```