# Method to rbind xts objects that removes duplicate rows

Tags: r, merge, time-series, xts, rbind

Is there any method currently for `xts` objects that rbinds columns by names and keeps either all of the first object's rows or second object's rows?

I can rbind data and then remove duplicate index entries, however I believe by default will keep the first object's rows when duplicated.

Comment: Related: [Remove duplicate rows from xts object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865257).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is an `xts` method for this, but we can still make it work, in at least a couple of ways.
If you look at `?rbind.xts` you'll see this:

> Identical indexed series are bound in the order or the arguments passed to rbind.

We can use that to our advantage.

First some example data

```
library(xts)

structure(c(5, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 5), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS
= "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", index =
structure(c(949449600, 949536000, 949708800, 949795200, 949881600,
949968000, 950054400, 950227200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim =
c(8L, 1L)) -> d1

structure(c(3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 5), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS
= "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", index =
structure(c(948931200, 949104000, 949190400, 949449600, 949536000,
949622400, 949708800, 950054400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim =
c(8L, 1L)) -> d2
```

If we then do an `rbind()` we'll get the duplicate values in the order we supplied `d1` and `d2`. We can then use `duplicated()` to find the duplicates, and negate (`!`) that index to deselect them.

```
dat.bind <- rbind(d1, d2)

dat.bind.d1 <- dat.bind[!duplicated(time(dat.bind))]
```

To select the other set of duplicated values we can either switch the the order of arguments in `rbind()`, or we can shift the boolean vector we created with `duplicated()` one to the left, and thereby deselect the first, rather than the second, of two identical values.

```
dat.bind.d2 <- dat.bind[c(!duplicated(time(dat.bind))[-1], TRUE)]
```

---

There is one caveat with this approach, and that is that `d1` and `d2` must not individually have duplicate indices. If we use `merge()` instead we don't have this limitation.

We do an outer join (maning all values are included, `NA`s filled in as necessary). Then we can simply replace the `NA`s in one column with values at the same index in the other column.

```
dat.merged <- merge(d1, d2, join="outer")

dat.merged.d1 <- replace(dat.merged[, 1], 
                         is.na(dat.merged[, 1]), 
                         dat.merged[is.na(dat.merged[, 1]), 2])

dat.merged.d2 <- replace(dat.merged[, 2], 
                         is.na(dat.merged[, 2]), 
                         dat.merged[is.na(dat.merged[, 2]), 1])
```