# rbind time series and drop identical dates

Tags: r, xts

Both `x` and `y` overlap on 2018-08-08. How can I combine the rows where I keep all values of `x`, then only retain values of `y` that do not overlap the same index/date value of `x`?

```
x <- as.xts(1:10, Sys.Date()+1:10). 
y <- as.xts(11:20, Sys.Date()+10:19). 
z <- rbind(x,y)

2018-07-30    1
2018-07-31    2
2018-08-01    3
2018-08-02    4
2018-08-03    5
2018-08-04    6
2018-08-05    7
2018-08-06    8
2018-08-07    9
2018-08-08   10
2018-08-08   11
2018-08-09   12
2018-08-10   13
2018-08-11   14
2018-08-12   15
2018-08-13   16
2018-08-14   17
2018-08-15   18
2018-08-16   19
2018-08-17   20
```

Should be missing the 2018-8-8 11 value for `y`

```
2018-07-30    1
2018-07-31    2
2018-08-01    3
2018-08-02    4
2018-08-03    5
2018-08-04    6
2018-08-05    7
2018-08-06    8
2018-08-07    9
2018-08-08   10
2018-08-09   12
2018-08-10   13
2018-08-11   14
2018-08-12   15
2018-08-13   16
2018-08-14   17
2018-08-15   18
2018-08-16   19
2018-08-17   20
```

Comment: Do you need `z[!duplicated(index(z)),]` ?

Comment: @RonakShah - that's almost certainly the answer - I'd just post it.

Comment: @RonakShah - yep, I agree. Though this is a clearer question than that one.

Comment: Thank you Ronak! This option works as well.

Comment: Related: [Method to rbind xts objects that removes duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541961/method-to-rbind-xts-objects-that-removes-duplicate-rows)

Comment: Thank you , this link is also another great option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subset the y's to omit those containing an index in x

`z <- rbind(x,y[!(index(y) %in% index(x))])`

Comment: Thanks Chris! That worked well. Really appreciate your time.

Comment: Any idea how to do.call this to merge more than 2 series?

Comment: using this to combine more than two xts objects would get tedious (e.g., something like `z <- rbind(x,y[!(index(y) %in% index(x))], m[!(index(m) %in% c(index(x), index(y))])` for a third object m. Ronak's solution (dropping duplicates after combining) seems simple enough.

Comment: yessir, thanks again